# Python file counts not matching

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I have a simple script to generate random essentially empty text files I am using as sandbox data for another project. For all intents and purposes it works but I noticed that the desired number of files to be generated and the actual count sometimes do not match if a value greater than 1500 is selected.

My code is as follows :

```
import os
import random
path = "data/"
def makeFiles():
    count = int(input("How many to make?\n"))   
    for x in range(0,count):
        num = random.randint(10000,999999)
        name = path+str(num)+".txt"
        f = open(name,"w")
        f.write(str(x))
        f.close()
        print(x)
makeFiles()
```

I am using Python 3.6 on Linux Mint ( which is essentially Ubuntu 16.04 ).  I felt that if I put a delay with time.sleep it may solve the issue but it didn't. When making 2500 files it will produce 2497 routinely at this point. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What stops `num = random.randint(10000,999999)` from producing the same random number twice, thus overwriting the first file you created?

Comment: replace `name = path+str(num)+".txt"`   by `name = path+str(x)+".txt" `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid duplicating numbers with `random.randint()` you could use `random.sample()`. With all the other recommendations (and stolen code) from @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.

**Update** @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ deleted his answer so here were his other recommendations:

2. Use `os.path.join` when joining paths
3. Use the `with...as` context manager to manage file I/O

E.g.:

```
for x, num in enumerate(random.sample(range(10000, 1000000), count)):        
    name = os.path.join(path, "{}.txt".format(num))
    with open(name, "w") as f:
        f.write(str(x))
```

Comment: Ah, the enumerate is a nice touch. +1

Comment: @AChampion as per OP the contents of the file should be the count, while the name should be rand. In your example it's the opposite.

Comment: @bulbus I would suggest looking at the documentation for [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), `x` is the count, `num` is the random number.

Comment: @AChampion arghgh, my bad!